# SQL Server Import Wizard: column in .csv that contains both my delimiter and my text qualifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

I'm trying to use the import wizard to import a CSV.  One column in my CSV contains both my delimiter (,) and my text qualifier ("):

...,"UV-blocking nanoparticles, Cancer therapy using **""magnetic vectoring""**, Hearing aid technology",...

It looks like excel escapes the double quote that's within the column, but it's killing the import wizard.  Any suggestions besides removing the double-quotes all together?

Comment: Is this a singe-instance import or are you going to do this multiple times?

Comment: @BiggsTRC - I have about 10 files to import now, each with anywhere between 50 and 2k rows.  It's one time for now, but I may be looking to save the SSIS package and schedule it in the future, so would like a cleaner solution if one is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one-time import, I would suggest doing a find and replace on the "forbidden" characters and then doing the reverse once the data is in SQL.  That may not be elegant, but it is simple.

Edit:  If you want to repeat this task and you have access to SSIS, skip the step of moving the data from Excel to a CSV and use SSIS to take the data right from Excel into SQL.